# How to properly use realloc in c?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define LENGHT 20

typedef struct {
    unsigned id;
    char name[LENGHT];
    char genre[LENGHT];
    char nazionality [LENGHT];
    int year_carrier_started;
    bool check;
}Artist;

void print(Artist *arr, int *i);
void addOne(Artist *arr, int *i);

int main(void) {

    int index = 5;
    Artist *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*index);
    for (int i=0;i<index;i++)
    {
        printf("Insert a number:\n");
        scanf("%d",&array[i].id);
    }
    do
    {
        addOne(array,&index);
        print(array,&index);
    }while(1);

    system("pause");
    free(array);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void addOne(Artist *arr, int *i)
{
    realloc(arr,sizeof(Artist)*(*i)+1);
    printf("Insert another one:\n");
    scanf("%d",&arr[*i].id);
    *i = *i +1;
    print(arr,i);
}


void print(Artist *arr, int *i)
{
    for (int j=0;j<*i;j++)
    {
        printf("Number: %d position %d\n",arr[j].id,j);
    }
}
```

Hi guys, I got this struct from a piece of my program, what I need to is to realloc everytime the user wants to add a new Artist. After adding like 10/15 more users, it crashes for no reason (at least for me there is not). What am I doing wrong? (Dat *i is passed by reference, it counts how many artists are there already).

Comment: Hint: Why +1 in `sizeof(Artist)*(*i)+1`?

Comment: `realloc` may move your data to another location, so you cannot trust that `arr` is still valid.  This is why realloc also returns the location of the memory allocated.

Comment: @chux yeah, I'm sorry about that, beucase I modify the *i at the of every statment so, I do that plus 1

Comment: is there a way to post my code with the fuctions? Unfortunatly, it is not recognized as code, so I need to Ctrl + k every line of it...

Comment: you can highlight a block of code and Ctrl + k once. And <O/T>, for your case it may not matter much, but consider `realloc`ing space for multiple `Artist`s at once. Memory allocation is a relatively expensive operation, and if you're doing a lot of them it can slow you down. Of course at the other extreme, you're allocating a huge swath of memory you won't use... it's a tradeoff

Comment: I edeted giving an MCVE

Comment: Have you tried reading a documentation first? for example :http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc For things from the standard library there are a lot good references found with a simple query to your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 4):

> How to properly use realloc in c(?)
>
> After adding like 10/15 more users, it crashes for <strike>no</strike> reason

[@Christian Gibbons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865445/how-to-properly-use-realloc-in-c/50865570#comment88733393_50865445) well advises: use the return value of `realloc()`.  The former value of `array` may not be valid.

---

#### Multiply the right values

```
// sizeof(Artist)*(*i)+1
sizeof(Artist)*((*i)+1)
```

#### Use the return value of `realloc()`

```
// realloc(array,sizeof(Artist)*(*i)+1);
void *new_ptr = realloc(array,....
```

#### Check realloc() results

```
// realloc(array,sizeof(Artist)*(*i)+1);
void *new_ptr = realloc(array,....
if (new_ptr == NULL) OutOfMemory();
else array = new_ptr;
```

#### Consider sizing by the object than the type

```
// realloc(array,sizeof(Artist)*(*i)+1);
void *new_ptr = realloc(array, sizeof *array *((*i)+1));
```

---

All together

```
Artist *array = malloc(sizeof *array);
if (array == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemory();
...
void *new_ptr = realloc(array, sizeof *array * ((*i)+ 1));
if (new_ptr == NULL) {
  // `array` still has *i elements assigned to it.
  Handle_OutOfMemory();
} else {
  array = new_ptr;
  (*i)++;
}
```

Comment: I edeted my post posting the code, could you help me from that?

Comment: @GeneNight I am confident that one can use this answer and apply it to your updated post.

Comment: @GeneNight `addOne(array,&index); .... void addOne(Artist *arr, int *i)` needs to pass the address of calling 
 `arr` too.  --> `addOne(&array,&index); ... void addOne(Artist **arr, int *i)`

Comment: What do you mean by "Handle_OutOfMemory()?

Comment: @GeneNight What would you like code to do if it runs out of allocatable memory? `Handle_OutOfMemory()` is placeholder code that embodies whatever your answer may be.  It might just be `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` for now for learner code.

Comment: @GeneNight Concerning [is still crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865445/how-to-properly-use-realloc-in-c/50865570#comment88734455_50865542), have you applied a fix to `addOne()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865445/how-to-properly-use-realloc-in-c/50865570#comment88733905_50865570)?

Answer (score 1):

`realloc` will attempt to resize your allocated memory in place if it can, but if there's not enough room to expand to the new size where it is, it will have to move the data to a new location.  Realloc returns a pointer to the location for this reason.  You should also test to make sure that it did not err.  So something like this:

```
Artist *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * i);
Artist *temp = realloc(arr, sizeof(Artist)*((*i)+1) // Borrowing this from Yunnosch
if(temp) {
    arr = temp;
}
else {
    free(arr);
    // more error handling
}
```

Comment: how is that is still crashes after adding like 100 more records? at least it handles some memories leak, and it works *5 more times anyway